# XMPP Connection with Pandion in .NET

Tags: c#

Please suggest me how to connect Pandion Chat Application with XMPP connection in .NET(C#).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a link to a c# library and some explanation: http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/